# R: Debugging Plotly Code - object not found (Time Series Analysis)

Tags: r, time-series, plotly, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to follow this tutorial over here for interactive time series visualization: https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/

I simulated some artificial data to match the structure of the data from the tutorial:

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

#create data

#time series 1
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data$class = "time_series_1"


#time series 2
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,10,10)

final_data_2 <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data_2 %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data_2$class = "time_series_2"

#combine
data = rbind(final_data, final_data_2)

data <- data %>%
 mutate(tmp_date = as.numeric(as.Date(date_decision_made, format = "%Y/%m/%d")))
```

From here, I tried to create the interactive plot:

```
updatemenus <- list(
  list(
    active = -1,
    type= 'buttons',
    buttons = list(
      list(
        label = "time_series_1",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE)),
                    list(title = "series 1",
                         annotations = list(c(), high_annotations)))),
      list(
        label = "time_series_2",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE)),
                    list(title = "series 2",
                         annotations = list(low_annotations, c() )))),
      
    )
  )

)

fig <- data %>% plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made,
  y=~property_damages_in_dollars, name="High",
  line=list(color="#33CFA5")) 
fig <- fig %>% add_lines(x=~date_decision_made, 
  y=~property_damage_in_dollars, name="Low",
  line=list(color="#F06A6A")) 
fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Apple", showlegend=FALSE,
                      xaxis=list(title="Date"),
                      yaxis=list(title="Price ($)"),
                      updatemenus=updatemenus)




fig
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
Error in layout.plotly(., title = "Apple", showlegend = FALSE, xaxis = list(title = "Date"),  : 
  object 'updatemenus' not found
```

I am not sure why this error is occurring. I have defined the "updatemenus" object above - is there a problem with the function definition?

Thanks

Comment: What is `high_annotations` and `low_annotations`?

Comment: Hi Ronak Shah, based on the tutorial over here: https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/ , it seems that "high_annotations" and "low_annotations" seem to be the two time series?